# How can I determine the needed version for a certain matlab function?

Tags: matlab

In my particular case I tried to use `svmtrain`. But this function is not available for my version/ toolboxes.

Now I wonder, is there an **easy** way to find out which version of matlab/ which toolbox is necessary to use this function?

Thx

Comment: I don't know about version, but Googleing the function it is pretty clear which toolbox you need.

Comment: Yeah, but there are also different version for the toolboxes.

Comment: If you just type `help functionname` in the command line you also can know if you have access to it or not.

Comment: Yes, I already noticed that I dont have access. I try to find out which version I have to purchase!

Comment: Why would you want to purchase the last one available?